# Select onChange - Testing using mount and react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a change event on a select options and check whether the call has been made. I tried with react-testing-library and mount. I get two different results. With react-testing-library I get error message

```
Expected: "CLOSE_REQUESTED"
Number of calls: 0
```

and with mount (2nd test), I get

```
Expected: "MEDIUM"
    Received
           1: {"_dispatchInstances": null, "_dispatchListeners": null, "_targetInst": {"_debugHookTypes": null, "_debugID": 369, "_debugIsCurrentlyTiming": false, "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": [FiberNode], "_debugSource": null, "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": -1, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childExpirationTime": 0, "dependencies": null, "effectTag": 128, "elementType": "select", "expirationTime": 0, "firstEffect": null, "index": 0, "key": null, "lastEffect": null, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": null, "mode": 0, "nextEffect": null, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": [Function anonymous], "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": <select … />, "tag": 5, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": "select", "updateQueue": null}, "bubbles": undefined, "cancelable": undefined, "currentTarget": null, "defaultPrevented": undefined, "dispatchConfig": {"dependencies": [Array], "phasedRegistrationNames": [Object]}, "eventPhase": undefined, "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isPersistent": [Function functionThatReturnsTrue], "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isTrusted": undefined, "nativeEvent": {"target": <select … />, "type": "change"}, "target": {"value": "MEDIUM"}, "timeStamp": 1593587446041, "type": "change"}
           2: {"bubbles": false, "cancelable": false, "currentTarget": <select class="oui-select oui-react-select" tabindex="0"><option value="MEDIUM">Standard</option></select>, "defaultPrevented": false, "eventPhase": 0, "isDefaultPrevented": [Function isDefaultPrevented], "isPropagationStopped": [Function isPropagationStopped], "isTrusted": false, "nativeEvent": {"isTrusted": false}, "persist": [Function persist], "preventDefault": [Function preventDefault], "stopPropagation": [Function stopPropagation], "target": <select class="oui-select oui-react-select" tabindex="0"><option value="MEDIUM">Standard</option></select>, "timeStamp": 1593587446042, "type": "change"}

Number of calls :2
```

Below is my component.

```
const ListFilter: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const onChangeStatus = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
    props.setSelectedFilter({
      status: evt.target.value,
      severity: props.selectedFilter.severity
    });
  };
  const onChangeSeverity = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
    props.setSelectedFilter({
      status: props.selectedFilter.status,
      severity: evt.target.value as TicketSeverityEnum
    });
  };
  return (
    <Select
          testId="status-select-id"
          value={props.selectedFilter.status}
          options={filterOptions.statusOptions}
          onChange={onChangeStatus}
        />

     <Select
          testId="severity-level-select-id"
          value={props.selectedFilter.severity}
          options={filterOptions.severitiesOptions}
          onChange={onChangeSeverity}
        />

  );
};
```

and below is my test

```
interface Props {
  incidentsVariant: QueryResult<IncidentSummary[]>;
  setSelectedFilter: (filter: FilterSelection) => void;
  selectedFilter: FilterSelection;
}
const mockSeveritiesOptions = [{ value: "MEDIUM", label: "Standard" }];

describe("ListFilter tests", () => {
  it("test ListIncidentFilter onChange Status", async () => {
    const onChangeStatusMock = jest.fn();
    const event = {
      target: { value: "CLOSE_REQUESTED" }
    } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
    const { getFirstByOuiTestId } = render(<Provider store={mockConnectorStore}><ListFilter {...mock}/></Provider>);
    const statusSelect = getFirstByOuiTestId("status-select-id");
    fireEvent.change(statusSelect,event);
    expect(onChangeStatusMock).toBeCalledWith("CLOSE_REQUESTED");
  });

it("test ListFilter onChange Severity", async () => {
    const onChangeSeverityMock = jest.fn();
    const event = {
      target: { value: "MEDIUM" }
    } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
    const component = mount(<Select onChange={onChangeSeverityMock} options={mockSeveritiesOptions} />);
    component.find("select").simulate("change", event);
    expect(onChangeSeverityMock).toBeCalledWith("MEDIUM");
  });
});
```

Why do I get two different results and how do I fix this tests?

Comment: `getFirstByOuiTestId` isn't a standard RTL query, is it a custom query? One test is just testing a `Select` component directly while the other is some wrapped version of `ListFilter`, the unit tests are testing completely different things.

Comment: You actually get the same result: your spies are not getting called. And it is reasonable, because you are creating and not passing them to the component to be called onChange